# calculate percentage for column for each value of another column sql

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the percentage of elected people for each member type,
I was able to do this:

```
SELECT Member, COUNT(Name) * 100 / 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'results' WHERE Member= '1' ) AS 'perc' 
FROM 'results' 
    WHERE elected='yes' AND Member = '1'
```

but I want to do it for all the member values (so also '0')

My table looks like this:

```
Name     member     Elected
----------------------------
joe      0          yes
ann      1          no
jef      0          no
```

this is the result I want:

```
Member    Percentage
---------------------
0         50%
1         0%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
select member,
  coalesce(count(case when elected = 'yes' then 1 end)/count(*), 0) * 100 Percentage
from results
group by member
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7651e/5)

Result:

```
| MEMBER | PERCENTAGE |
-----------------------
|      0 |         50 |
|      1 |          0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Member, 
   Sum(Case When elected='yes' Then 1 
            Else 0 End) / COUNT(*) 'perc' 
FROM 'results' 
group by Member
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
SELECT Member, 
(COUNT(Case When elected='yes' Then 1 Else NULL End) / COUNT(*)) * 100 'perc' 
FROM 'results'     
group by Member
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`Group By Member`**

If you use [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) then it would be easy to help you.

Stealing from **bluefeet** Here you go

```
select member,
  concat(FLOOR(coalesce(count(case when elected = 'yes' then 1 end)/count(*), 0) * 100), '%')  Percentage
from results
group by member
```